# Two, actually three, identical tags — autolayout, ios-autolayout, nsautolayout

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

These three tags are utterly pointless; they are, absolutely, the same thing.

[autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolayout), [ios-autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-autolayout), [nsautolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsautolayout)

[image]

They should all be **autolayout** as a synonym or whatever.

Comment: Are there differences between iOS and macOS? Because if so, ios-autolayout might have some merit but I'm not an SME.

Comment: all are identical

Comment: So a synonym would work then? Autolayout being the master? Because that is less invasive then a mass re-tag.

Answer (score 3):

The synonymy between [autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolayout) and [ios-autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-autolayout) was already proposed by Milan Nosáľ back in Feb 27 '18, I approved the synonym. I also added [nsautolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsautolayout) as a synonym. I kept the [autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolayout) tag as the master, as it had 10 times the size of the other two tags *combined*. I've created the synonyms as follows:

[nsautolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsautolayout) (× 171) → [autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolayout) (× 10490)
[ios-autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-autolayout) (× 1068) → [autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolayout) (× 10490)

And as usual, I'll merge the tags after a few days, if there aren't any issues with the synonym.

Comment: Say Bhargav, do you work for SO, or just a generous contributor?   Looks like you did an amazing job !

Comment: I'm just a volunteer here. Thanks for the kind words, they do mean a lot to me.

Comment: Your efforts are generous to the point where SO should be sending you money - after ~4 years of nobody doing anything, you alone did everything.  THANKS FROM ALL IOS USERS.

Comment: As one of the writers of popular iOS answers, I am declaring today **International Bhargav Rao Day**.  Thank you, thank you !!!!!!!!!!!  IBRD begins !!!!!!!!!!!